# Phaser.Loader - error loading asset from URL

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm struggling getting a simple image to load via Phaser.Loader. Following the example [here](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/tree/master/resources/Project%20Templates/Responsive). I keep getting the following error:

[image]

[image]

Whats strange is that looking at the network tab in Chrome shows these resources loading fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem. Those images I was referencing were corrupted. Strange since I got them right from the phaser github.

Answer (score 0):

you did not load the images in preload method or the images are not loaded in Cache. I think loading images in **preload** method can solve the problem and make sure you assign the image path correctly.

`function preload(){
 this.load.image('myimage','asset/myimage.png');
}`

Comment: They're all in `preload()`.